# Assigning a class in a .erb clause, "syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All, I'm getting the following syntax error when trying to assign a class in an erb file:

```
SyntaxError in Posts#index

Showing [..]/app/views/posts/_post.html.erb where line #5 raised:

[..]/app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
...append= ( post.title, :class => 'my-custom-class' );@output_...
...     

                      ^ 
3:   <td>
4:     <div>
5:       <%= post.title, :class => 'my-custom-class' %>
6:     </div>
7: </td>
```

I could add the class into the `<div>` - namely `<div class='my-custom-class'> .. </div>`, but is there not a more elegant way, without the div, embedding the class assignment in the erb clause?

Ideas here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= content_tag, :div, post.title, :class => 'my-custom-class' %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag